# How to safely show messagebox in multi-thread application?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have something doing background and I want to show a messagebox if something wrong happens.
First I tried

```
var _timer = new System.Threading.Timer((o) =>
{
    if(!DoCheck()){
        Messagebox.Show("The message");
    }
});
```

Nothing wrong happens.

And I have another job to be done in background, and it's invoked by button click, like

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var task = new Task(() =>
    {
        DoWork();
        Messagebox.Show("Done");
    });
    _task.Start();
}
```

A `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException` is thrown when the `MessageBox` is shown.

I have also tried `this.Invoke`, it raised an exception, too.
My question is:

1. Is the first case safe?
2. How to make the second case work?

Comment: If this is a Desktop application, then you can check `BackgroundWorker` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that is supposed to be used for such cases

Answer (score 0):

1. No. You should preferably be using `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` in a WinForms application. [The documentation specifically calls this out:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> This Windows timer is designed for a single-threaded environment where UI threads are used to perform processing. It requires that the user code have a UI message pump available and always operate from the same thread, or marshal the call onto another thread.

Furthermore, it depends on what your `DoCheck` method is doing. We will need to see the code of that method.

2. Use the `BeginInvoke` method:

   ```
   var form = this;
   var task = new Task(() =>
   {
       DoWork();
       form.BeginInvoke(() => 
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Done");
       });
   });
   ```

Comment: It it safe to BeginInvoke() in the first case?