# Databinding between Model and Label using a Timer

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I am trying to bind my Label's `Text` property to the Model's `Counter` property, but it's not updating with every timer increment.

This might be a duplicated question but I really do not understand where I've made a mistake.

It looks like it can take the initial value, but it doesn't update every second like it is supposed to.

In the Form Constructor:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Model model;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        model = new Model();

        Binding binding = new Binding("Text", model, "Counter", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        label1.DataBindings.Add(binding);
    }
}
```

My **`Model`** class:

```
public class Model: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property.
    // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName
    // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument.
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(propertyName);
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private static Timer timer;
    private int counter;

    public int Counter
    {
        get { return counter; }
        set 
        { 
            counter = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public Model()
    {
        counter = 0;
        SetTimer();
    }

    public void SetTimer()
    {
        timer = new Timer(1000);
        timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
        timer.AutoReset = true;
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Counter++;            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of examples, using a [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer) that replaces the [System.Timers.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer) you're using now.
The latter raises its `Elapsed` event in ThreadPool Threads. DataBindings, as many other objects, don't work cross-Thread.

You can read some other details here:
[Why does invoking an event in a timer callback cause following code to be ignored?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60465384/7444103)

The `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` is instead already *synchronized*, its `Tick` event is raised in the UI Thread.

New Model class using this Timer:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "") 
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    private readonly Timer timer;
    private int counter;

    public Model() {
        counter = 0;
        timer = new Timer() { Interval = 1000 };
        timer.Tick += this.Timer_Elapsed;
        StartTimer();
    }

    public int Counter {
        get => counter;
        set {
            if (counter != value) {
                counter = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public void StartTimer() => timer.Start();

    public void StopTimer() => timer.Stop();

    private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e) => Counter++;

    public void Dispose(){
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing) {
            lock (this) {
                if (timer != null) timer.Tick -= Timer_Elapsed;
                timer?.Stop();
                timer?.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

In case you want to use a `System.Threading.Timer`, you need to synchronize its [Elapsed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.elapsed) event with the UI Thread, since, as mentioned, a PropertyChanged notification cannot be marshalled across Threads and your DataBindings won't work.

You can use (mainly) two methods:

- Use the [SynchronizationContext](http://SynchronizationContext) class to capture the current `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` and [Post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.post) to it to update a Property value.
- Add a Constructor to your class that also accepts an UI element that implements [ISynchronizeInvoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.isynchronizeinvoke) (any Control, in practice). You can use this object to set the `System.Threading.Timer`'s [SynchronizingObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.synchronizingobject) property.
  When set, the `Elapsed` event will be raised in the same Thread as the Sync object.

Note: You cannot declare a Model object as a Field and initialize at the same time: there's no SynchronizationContext until after the starting Form has been initialized. You can initialize a new Instance in the Constructor of a Form or any time after:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Model model = new Model(); // <= Won't work
    // ------------------------------------------
    Model model = null;        // <= It's OK
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Using the SynchronizationContext
        model = new Model();

        // Or, using A Synchronizing Object
        model = new Model(this);

        var binding = new Binding("Text", model, "Counter", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        label1.DataBindings.Add(binding);
    }
}
```

A modified Model class that makes use of both:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Timers;

public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    internal readonly SynchronizationContext syncContext = null;
    internal ISynchronizeInvoke syncObj = null;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    private System.Timers.Timer timer;
    private int counter;

    public Model() : this(null) { }

    public Model(ISynchronizeInvoke synchObject)
    {
        syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        syncObj = synchObject;
        timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.SynchronizingObject = syncObj;
        timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
        StartTimer(1000);
    }

    public int Counter {
        get => counter;
        set {
            if (counter != value) {
                counter = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public void StartTimer(int interval) {
        timer.Interval = interval;
        timer.AutoReset = true;
        timer.Start();
    }

    public void StopTimer(int interval) => timer.Stop();

    private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (syncObj is null) {
            syncContext.Post((spcb) => Counter += 1, null);
        }
        else {
            Counter += 1;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing) {
            lock (this) {
                if (timer != null) timer.Elapsed -= Timer_Elapsed;
                timer?.Stop();
                timer?.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```